# Check the transcription job status

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

I encounter an exception with **Amazon Transcribe** when I try to get the transcription result.
I haven't found a way to pass a callback or receive a notification when the transcription is done. So I regularly check if the result is available.

Here is my code:

```
var getTranscriptionJobRequest = new GetTranscriptionJobRequest()
{
    TranscriptionJobName = fileName
};

// Regularly check the request status
GetTranscriptionJobResponse getTranscriptionJobResponse;
do
{
  Thread.Sleep(250); // Wait 250 ms
  getTranscriptionJobResponse = amazonTSClient.GetTranscriptionJob(getTranscriptionJobRequest);
}
while (getTranscriptionJobResponse.TranscriptionJob.TranscriptionJobStatus != TranscriptionJobStatus.COMPLETED);
```

And here is the exception:

```
Amazon.TranscribeService.AmazonTranscribeServiceException: 'Rate exceeded'
```

I found [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=36831) that the error is due to too many requests to the AWS API.

So, my question is:

**Is it possible to be notified when the transcription result is available?**
**Or if not, what is the maximum call rate to the AWS API?**

Comment: I don't know amazon, but it looks like you are starting the job every 250 ms.

Comment: No, I get the result object from AWS to check its status every 250 ms.
The job is started before with this code:
`amazonTSClient.StartTranscriptionJobAsync(new StartTranscriptionJobRequest() { /*...*/ });`

Answer (score 1):

Notification from AWS Transcribe relies on its integration with AWS CloudWatch. Example cloud watch rule:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.transcribe"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Transcribe Job State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "TranscriptionJobStatus": [
      "COMPLETED",
      "FAILED"
    ]
  }
}
```

Resulting event in CloudWatch:

```
 {
   "version": "0",
   "id": "event ID",
   "detail-type":"Transcribe Job State Change",
   "source": "aws.transcribe",
   "account": "account ID",
   "time": "timestamp",
   "region": "region",
   "resources": [],
   "detail": {
     "TranscriptionJobName": "unique job name",
     "TranscriptionJobStatus": "status"
   }
 }
```

More info:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/cloud-watch-events.html

If polling instead, the maximum call rate of GetTranscriptionJob is ~3 per second.  That and other rate limits are documented here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits-amazon-transcribe

Comment: `detail` always returns null for me :( here's the response I get 

`'version' => '0',
  'id' => '1fa5cca6-413f-4a0f-0ba2-66efa49c247e',
  'detail-type' => 'Transcribe Job State Change',
  'source' => 'aws.transcribe',
  'account' => '405723091079',
  'time' => '2019-11-19T19:04:25Z',
  'region' => 'eu-west-1',
  'detail' => NULL,
`

Comment: Strange. I just ran a quick test and I do get a valid detail.  Can you use the AWS console to verify the job completed successfully?   How are you acquiring that response? i.e. I used a simple SNS topic to email it to myself. Consider posting this as a new question on SO for better visibility.